# error 400 when I try to use an API (Python)

Tags: python, gtfs

I am trying to use the API from Société du Métro de Montréal (STM), a transportation GTFS transportation API.

I get error code 400 ("Too many requests") when trying the Python code below. I wonder if anyone is working with transportation APIs and can give me some hints on what I did wrong.

```py
import requests
api_key = "API-KEY-FROM-DEVELOPER-ACCOUNT"
api_url = f"https://api.stm.info/pub/od/gtfs-rt/ic/v2/vehiclePositions"

# Prepare the request headers with the API key
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
     }

# Send the HTTP GET request to the API endpoint
response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)

# if you get 200 as response... everything ok
print("response.status_code",response.status_code)

# Check if the request was successful (status code 200)

if response.status_code == 200:
    try:
        # Parse the JSON response
        data = response.json()

        # Process and use the retrieved data as needed
        print(data)
    except ValueError as e:
        print("Error parsing JSON:", e)
        print("Response content:", response.text)
else:
    # Handle unsuccessful request
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
```

I expected a response 200 for:

```py
print("response.status_code",response.status_code)
```

***LATER UPDATE***
Actually the issue was in the authentication method. I replaced the headers by the ones below and it gave me the response 200, confirming that I was able to connect to the API.
= issue closed

headers = {
"apiKey":api_key,
"Content-Type": "application/json"
}

Thanks to all who tried to help... and thanks a lot to ChatGPT !!!
:)

Comment: How do you know that URL is valid? Can you provide a link to the corresponding API documentation?

Comment: the error is with the url itself , try to double check the url if correct or not .

Comment: it's either as @zainal-abdeen said, or your internet isn't working, you're behind a firewall, or some such other user error thing

Comment: Running your code here gives me a `400` status (I sent a dummy API key, so it makes sense). You are probably behind a firewall or the service was unavailable when you tested.

Comment: if you use a proxy, indicate the proxy address via the [`proxies` argument](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies).

Comment: @larsks: Thanks for your message. The developpers site is [link] (https://www.stm.info/en/about/developers) _italic_ **bold**. I pasted a screenshot of the location where it describes the API URL to use. I contacted via email the transportation authority to get them confirm the URL and authentication method (headers), but no answer so far.

Comment: @nonDucor : Right, I run it again and it gives me Error Code 400. This is weird, as it is usually for reaching the maximum number of requests (10 requests/second) and I just did three or four in 10 min.

Comment: @Remi Cuingnet : I am not using a proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fiddling (in the APIs page you can try the APIs real time), I found out that the field name for the API key is `apikey`. Thus, the following code should work:

```py
import requests
api_key = "API-KEY-FROM-DEVELOPER-ACCOUNT"
api_url = f"https://api.stm.info/pub/od/gtfs-rt/ic/v2/vehiclePositions"

# Prepare the request headers with the API key
headers = {
    "apikey": api_key,
     }

# Send the HTTP GET request to the API endpoint
response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers);

print(f"{response.status_code}: {response.content}")
```

A few points to notice:

1. Your API key will only be available after you **publish** your application. The option will be on the bottom of the application editing screen. If your "Application" is not showing "Enabled", you didn't finish it and your API key will not work.
2. The response is a protobuf, not a json.

It will be easier to use the [Python language bindings](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/examples/python-sample) to read the results. You can use the example below (adapted to python3):

```py
from google.transit import gtfs_realtime_pb2
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

api_key = "API-KEY-FROM-DEVELOPER-ACCOUNT"
api_url = f"https://api.stm.info/pub/od/gtfs-rt/ic/v2/vehiclePositions"

feed = gtfs_realtime_pb2.FeedMessage()
request = Request(api_url)
request.add_header('apikey', api_key)
response = urlopen(request)

print(f'Status: {response.status_code}')

feed.ParseFromString(response.read())
for i, entity in enumerate(feed.entity):
  if entity.HasField('vehicle') and entity.vehicle.HasField('position'):
    pos = entity.vehicle.position
    print(f'{i} lat: {pos.latitude}, long: {pos.longitude}')
```